# Can I store username in s3 as text file to reduce redundancy in nosql database?

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, nosql, scalability, system-design

We are developing a social networking app which has these two tables in my our NoSQL database
Users table

```
eg:)
{
   id: 123,
   username: '@frank',
}
```

Posts table

```
eg:)
{
    _id: 1,
    caption: 'My Photo',
    imageUrl: 'socialnetwork.s3.com/image.jpg',
    username: 'socialnetwork.s3.com/PermanentUserId/username.txt',
    userId: 'PermanentUserId'
}
```

In the Home feed, we're displaying the posts with the username and caption.

To fetch the posts with its owner's username, we don't want to join the posts table with the users table.

we also don't want to store the username directly in the posts table. Suppose if the User changes their username I need to update that in all of their post.

So we're storing the username as a text file in s3 like this socialnetwork.s3.com/PermanentUserId/username.txt

The username.txt file in the s3 will have @frank

we will call the s3 username URL to get the actual username from the frontend.

In the future, if the user changes their username I don't need to update all the of their records in the posts table. I just need to update the username.txt in s3.

Is this a good approach?

If I use s3 with Cloudfront caching, would this scale to millions of users?

If this is wrong, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many systems paralysed by poor up-front decisions, such as using an email address as the unique ID for a user. So, it's good you're thinking of this now!

I would recommend that you **assign a unique ID to each user**, and then refer to that user in all locations via that unique ID. The ID should *not* be their username or email address. Those would be *attributes* stored in the user record.

NoSQL databases like DynamoDB do not allow joining between tables, so you would need to retrieve the user's unique ID first, then use it to find entries in other tables.

You can think of Amazon S3 as being a NoSQL database (key=filename, value=contents of the object), but rather than storing the username within a file as you suggest, it should really just be part of the user's entry in the User table.